# delete query doesn't work via php pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-delete

I am trying to use the following code:

```
$Q = DBCon::getCon()->prepare('SELECT * FROM `'.$language['data_table_name'].'` WHERE `id`=:id');
$Q->bindValue(':id', $recordId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$Q->execute();
var_dump($Q);
var_dump($recordId);
var_dump($Q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

$Q = DBCon::getCon()->prepare('DELETE FROM `'.$language['data_table_name'].'` WHERE `id`=:id');
$Q->bindValue(':id', $recordId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$Q->execute();
var_dump($Q);
var_dump($recordId);
```

which generates the following data via `var_dump`:

```
object(PDOStatement)[6]
  public 'queryString' => string 'SELECT * FROM `project_nl` WHERE `id`=:id' (length=41)

string '5' (length=1)

array (size=4)
  'id' => int 5
  'name' => string 'test' (length=4)
  'description' => string 'test' (length=4)
  'big_image' => string 'test' (length=4)

object(PDOStatement)[6]
  public 'queryString' => string 'DELETE FROM `project_nl` WHERE `id`=:id' (length=39)

string '5' (length=1)
```

Which should, as far as I know, delete the record where `id` equals `5` from the following table:

```
|Table name: project_nl               |
---------------------------------------
| id | name | description | big_image |
---------------------------------------
| 1  | test | test        | test      |
| 5  | test | test        | test      |
```

However, the piece of code doesn't actually delete anything. Neither does it throw any errors/exceptions.

When I, however, copy the query from the `var_dump` and paste it into phpMyAdmin, the row does get deleted.

Also, the script is full of working `insert`, `update` and `select` queries which all work fine. It's only `DELETE` which doesn't do anything at all.

Comment: Why are you explicitly binding it as PARAM_STR and not _INT? Isn't it a numeric column? Do you get any results when switching DELETE for SELECT in this code section?

Comment: @mario I changed it to `PARAM_INT`, and added a `select` query with it's output.

Comment: Perhaps a dangling transaction? Else try to use a plain query, instead of a prepared statement -- for testing.

Comment: Thanks alot! I disabled auto commit, and didnt start nor commit a transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disabled auto commit, and didnt start nor commit a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDBPDO";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // sql to delete a record
    $sql = "DELETE FROM MyGuests WHERE id=3";

    // use exec() because no results are returned
    $conn->exec($sql);
    echo "Record deleted successfully";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }

$conn = null;
?>
```